# Send an email with different senders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, actionmailer

I have an application that enables the seller send an email to his client.
How can I set the sender of the email as the email of the seller?

Example:

> E-mail A: { from: "steve@domain.com", to: "client@whatever.com" }
>   E-mail B: { from: "andrew@other-domain.com", to: "blabla@client.com }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using ActionMailer:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionMailer/Base.html

You will see that in the `mail` method you can give arguments like to, bcc, from, subject, body, etc !

Using their example:

```
class ApplicationMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def welcome(recipient, sender) # where sender is a String like "an-email@address.com"
    mail(:to => recipient, :from => sender, :subject => "Here is what we look like")
  end
end
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't worked. When I receive it, the "from" field is replaced by the authenticated email address (the one I set in the ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings)

Comment: Did you find a way to fix this, Lucas Moreira?

Comment: Usually you can't overwrite the sender email (I know that gmail won't allow that) for obvious security reasons (I could send an email to someone from an address I don't own) @MPorto

Comment: @MrYoshiji : Is there any way around that, though? I am building an app that guides the user through writing an email, after which it should offer the user the option to send that to anyone they want to (but with their email as the sender). Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: This depends on the Mail "provider" you use. This is not an issue solvable with Ruby/Rails, it really depends on the provider of the mail service. Example: If you want your end-users to be able to send emails with their own email address, you would need their credentials to authenticate to their mail provider (hotmail, gmail, etc), and send an email from their account. You can't decide which "from" address you put in the mails you send, you can only use the one that your Rails' app is authenticated to.